# How to check if user input is typed before?

Tags: java, if-statement, input, evaluation

I have created a hangman-game.

I want to ask how I can check if the user type the same letter. Everything is working fine but without checking if the number is allready typed.

```
if (word.contains(input)) {
        i = i - 1;
        char[] charOfGameBoard = gameBoard.toCharArray();
        for (int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++) {
            if (word.charAt(x) != input.charAt(0)) {
                continue;
            }

            int j = x * 2;
            charOfGameBoard[j] = input.charAt(0);
        }

        gameBoard = String.valueOf(charOfGameBoard);

    }
```

I cant post to much sry.

> word = "house"
>
> charOfGameBoard= _ _ _ _ _
>
> userinput= "h"     //Correct
>
> charOfGameBoard =h _ _ _ _
>
> userinput= "h" // incorrect at this point
>
> charOfGameBoard =h _ _ _ _

Comment: why not keep an array of guessed letters, and see if the guessed letters contains the input before you check to see if the word contains the input?

Comment: that would be my solution but I want to see if anyone has a better solution. For it would be not clean to have an Array with all letter of alphabet. But I think to save the inputs letter in a array.

Comment: Why not? Besides, it's not like hangman is a memory intensive or resource consuming application. I suggest you store the values in an array and check to see if it's in the array before you test it against the word

Comment: I dont know how to check if a letter is typed 2 times. Because the first time is allowed and the second one is not allowed. Maybe with a empty array?

Comment: start with am empty array, i.e. 'lettersGuessed', see if lettersGuessed contains the 'input', if it does not, add the input to the lettersGuessed array. The next time that same letter is guessed it will check against 'lettersGuessed', and you'll be able to stop it from going into your 'if' statement you posted above

Comment: Is there some kind of *create hangman* exercise ongoing? A hour ago: [hangman-check-if-string-is-contained-in-the-word-and-replace-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44812465/hangman-check-if-string-is-contained-in-the-word-and-replace-it). Check out the answers, it may be helpful for you too.

Answer (score 2):

You could store the guesses in a `HashSet`

```
  HashSet<char> guessedLetters = new HashSet();
  ...
  boolean success = guessedLetters.Add(input)
```

A `HashSet` can only contain one of each value, the `Add` method will return false if the set already contains the element being added.

https://www.javatpoint.com/java-hashset

Comment: Little Question, is there a another way without Hash, just primitive Arrays?

Comment: You would need to make an array of size 26, when you get an input loop through the array and check if its already there, if not, add the new lettter  to the array. But why would you want to do it this way?

Comment: ty you so much, You guys helped me.

Comment: Because of my Teacher he is very strict but I think I just explain it to him why I am using HashSet

Comment: A HastSet is the correct data structure to use, you will only be manually replicating this functionality otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the characters to an array list as they are entered and check if you have seen the letter before:

```
ArrayList<Character> usedLetters = new ArrayList<>();
public boolean UserTypedLetterBefore(char letter) {
    if(usedLetters.contains(letter))
        return true;

    usedLetters.add(letter);
    return false;
}
```

Then when the game is over you just call `usedLetters.clear()` to empty the list and start over. This method can also keep track of the number of guesses by doing `usedLetters.size()` because each guess is one letter

---

If you want to be extra efficient, you can use a `HashSet` instead (although it is unnecessary in your case):

```
HashSet<Character> usedLetters = new HashSet<>();
public boolean UserTypedLetterBefore(char letter) {
    if(usedLetters.contains(letter))
        return true;

    usedLetters.add(letter);
    return false;
}
```

This will be the ideal option for larger data sets but in your case since you only have 26 possible letters, you won't notice a speed difference.

---

A third option is to use a primitive array, as such:

```
boolean[] usedLetters = new boolean[26];
public boolean UserTypedLetterBefore(char letter) {
    letter = Character.toLowerCase(letter);

    if(usedLetters[letter - 'a'])
        return true;

    usedLetters[letter - 'a'] = true;
    return false;
}
```

Where each index is a flag for that letter being used. By performing math on the character `letter - 'a'` we can make `'a' = 0` so we can use it as the index in our array we need. The `Character.toLowerCase()` is added as a safety.

Comment: is there a way without List or Maps? So just primitive Array?

Comment: @ManuellsenDeve Updated

Comment: Ty so much. I think I just take the List or Hash its simply and faster.

Comment: @ManuellsenDeve I would agree. But it is also good to know how to approach it in an array :) All the approaches have tradeoffs but in your case it really won't make a difference.

Comment: You ought to mark this as the answer @ManuellsenDeve

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a `List` of guesses, and add another condition in your `if` statement, like this:

```
List<String> guesses = new ArrayList<>();

if (word.contains(input) && !guesses.contains(input)) {
    guesses.add(input);
    //...
    //all of your other code
    //...
}
```